# Sympy: derivative and subs

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I have this code:

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol("x")
f = Function("f")(x)
diff(3*x + 2, x) # == 3
diff(f, x).subs(f, 3*x + 2) # == Derivative(3*x + 2, x) <- Why not 3?
```

Why `sympy` not evaluates the expression when I substituted for `f` the expression with `x`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`diff(f, x)` can't derivate the function yet, so it results in the abstract `Derivative(f(x), x)`. Substitution doesn't do any evaluation, so substituting `f` for `3*x + 2` results in `Derivative(3*x + 2, x)`. If you want to evaluate it, just append `doit()`:

```
>>> diff(f, x).subs(f, 3*x + 2).doit()
3
```